# Why i didn't see in "External Libraries" my dependecies?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I set libraries in module dependecies
[image]

But in "External Libraries" i see only java and groovy.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the jar-files were inside the current project folder. As soon as I brought them to the external separate folder - they appeared in the "External Libraries" list. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Well it must be because you didn't export them. Take a look at the image and click Export all you need for exporting.

> Export. This option lets you control the compilation classpath for the
>   modules that depend on this one.
>
> Select the checkbox if you want the item to be exported as a
>   dependency along with the module. That is, if there is a module that
>   depends on this one, the items with the Export option on will be
>   included in the compilation classpath of the dependent module.

I strongly advise using

> maven-dependency-plugin

however.

Comment: flag "Export" unfortunately did not help. Maven is realy good solution, but dont work with groovy pre-compilation